# Auto detect rotation and rotate video accordingly with java, ffmpeg

Tags: video, rotation, ffmpeg, autorotate

Can anyone please help me with this?

On converting videos to SWF, MOV files are rotated 90 degrees by default. I am using the JAVE Swf Converter and the [JAVE](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/download.php) Encoder.

If I use:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov -vf "transpose=1" out.mov
```

All mov files are getting rotated, but what I need is to automatically detect just the rotated videos and change orientation for just those videos. Please help.

How can I automatically detect the rotation or orientation of the video during upload and rotate if needed, so that all "mov" files play in the correct orientation?

Thanks,
Lakshmi Priya.K